# How can I print the content of an array in a variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to use the output of the first array (Locale) in a second array. Unfortunately I have been unable to get it to work.

```
#!/bin/sh

locale=(ch de es fr in pl it be)

webuser=apache

for locale in "${locale[@]}"
do
    echo -n "\"./public/$locale/*\" "
done < <(local_dirs)

for folder in "${local_dirs[@]}"
do
    echo "sudo chown -R $webuser $folder"
    #sudo chown -R $webuser $folder
    echo "sudo chmod -R 775 $folder"
    #sudo chmod -R 775 $folder
done
```

I not even sure it's possible, I can always print it to a file.

Regards,
Kim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first for-loop is incorrect:

```
for locale in "${locale[@]}"
do
    echo -n "\"./public/$locale/*\" "
done < <(local_dirs)
```

You are looping over the `locale` array but you are also redirecting `local_dirs` into the for-loop which doesn't make sense and will not work.

If you want to store the output of the for-loop into an array, you would do it like this:

```
locale=(ch de es fr in pl it be)
local_dirs=( $(for locale in "${locale[@]}"
               do
                   echo -n "\"./public/$locale/*\" "
               done) 
           )
```

The general syntax to store the output of a command into an array is: `myarray=( $(command) )`

However, in this case, you don't need a second array. You could achieve the same thing like this:

```
for loc in "${locale[@]}"
do
    folder="\"./public/$loc/*\" "
    echo "sudo chown -R $webuser $folder"
    #sudo chown -R $webuser $folder
    echo "sudo chmod -R 775 $folder"
    #sudo chmod -R 775 $folder
done
```

Comment: nice answer, but you should also change the 3rd loop: 1) `folder="./public/$loc/*"`  (the original was trying to surround with quotes and added a separating space, but it's not part of the folder name!)  2) change the echo : `echo sudo chown -R "${webuser}" "${folder}"`  and  `echo sudo chmod -R 775 "${folder}"`  (that way, just removing the "echo" will instead launch the command. And the quotes are needed in case folders have space, etc, in them.  And the 2nd loop as well should be edited to not add quotes and a trailing space in the folder name

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you mean, but would this work:

```
locale=(ch de es fr in pl it be)

webuser=apache

for locale in "${locale[@]}"
do
    folder=`echo -n "\"./public/$locale/*\" "`
    echo "sudo chown -R $webuser $folder"
    #sudo chown -R $webuser $folder
    echo "sudo chmod -R 775 $folder"
    #sudo chmod -R 775 $folder
done
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in your snippet, so this would not work.

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed that. Was missing `do` :P

Comment: No, I am talking about the spaces enclosing the `=` ;-)

Comment: Indeed. Fixed that one as well :) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your first loop could simply be:

```
for a_locale in "${locale[@]}"
do
    local_dirs+=("\"./public/${a_locale}/*\"")
done
```

Please try and verify it does indeed add to "local_dirs" each elements (as I can't try it right now myself)

Note: avoid using the same name for the "locale" array and "locale" variable! (That's why I changed it to "a_locale" here)

(AND you need to avoid any reserved words, for variable names, so I usually use "a_name" to make sure there are no collisions)

Comment: I'm not sure why you need two separate loops, though :) (though it won't hurt much, and maybe you need the local_dirs list for something else) (I guess this comment is more for OP, and not you)

Comment: @SvendHansen: it is indeed more for the OP ^^ I guess he simplified the script, and may need to keep the array for some other uses (or he just wants to know how to it)